# TimeCrowdsale.open() always returns as closed after deployed to development network

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

In a nutshell Im not understanding why my deployed TimedCrowdsale never opens

Deploying a TimeCrowdsale contract to the Truffle development network

In my migration script I deploy the TimeCrowdsale contract.
After deployment I realise the crowdsale never gets to open state. Every time i run the debug script i get the same result.

```
Executing crowdsale_debug.js
crowdsale open?: false
crowdsale opening time: 1641354700
crowdsale closing time: 1641355000

Latest block timestamp: 1641354615
```

The isOpen() function of the TimedCrowdsale.sol is as follow

```
function isOpen() public view returns (bool) {
        return block.timestamp >= _openingTime && block.timestamp <= _closingTime;
    }
```

I know that in testing you can use the openzep testhelpers to advance time. But how will I do so outside of testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block timestamp is lower than the opening time. So this part of the expression returns `false`

```
// 1641354615 >= 1641354700 // false
block.timestamp >= _openingTime
```

which causes the `isOpen()` function to return `false`.

---

You can increase the Ganache (Truffle development network) time using the `evm_increaseTime` JSON-RPC method, passing it the amount of seconds as the only parameter.

Outside of the test script, you can send a CURL request to your local Ganache network:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:7545 \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "jsonrpc": "1.0",
    "id": "curltest",
    "method": "evm_increaseTime",
    "params": [
      100000
  ]
}'
```

Comment: yes i know this already. This was quite obvious. My question is why is my block not advancing? And how do i get it to advance so that my crowdsale eventually opens?

Comment: @L-Samuels My bad, I misread your question. I extended the answer with a way to increase the emulator time from outside of the test script.

Comment: Thank you @Petr Hejda. This is what I needed. I've marked as the answer.